# Error uploading documents that have null values for longitude and latitude (geo_point) in Elastic 7.15

Tags: elastic-stack, kibana-7

I am using the "Upload File" option to upload csv file that has some values of longitude and latitude as null in Elastic 7.15. The Mappings and Ingest pipeline are as below

**Mapping**...

```
"Latitude": {
      "type": "double"
    },
    "Longitude": {
      "type": "double"
    },
    "UniqueID": {
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    "Unit Number": {
      "type": "long"
    },
    "User ID": {
      "type": "long"
    },
    "location": {
      "type": "geo_point"
    }
...
```

**Ingest pipeline**

```
...
{
      "set": {
        "field": "location",
        "value": "{{Latitude}},{{Longitude}}"
      }
    }
....
```

location field is auto added (combined fields)

When I import the csv with these settings, i am getting error that documents that are empty could not be imported

> Error: 8: failed to parse field [location] of type [geo_point]
> {"message":"1143266,1/4/2021,E BRECKENRIDGE 1000.0 FT E OF BERMUDA,,,1,"2,186,198""}

I would like to be able to import documents that have null values for coordinates while keeping the type as geo_point since I am creating map visualization. If I remove **Set** on location or add script  `"if": "ctx.latitude_field != null && ctx.longitude_field != null"`, to **Set**, I can upload all the docs, but then map visualization does not show any documents for location field

Answer (score 1):

I was able to bypass this issue by adding a new field Location(concat(lat,long)) in the csv and updating mapping and removing Set.